# Blinking PWR when not enough current available?

Tags: usb-power, board-leds

I'm not sure whether I've seen mention of this here before or not.

Anyway, I have a B+ with `max_usb_current=1` enabled so I can run an external USB drive off it.  There's never been a problem with this, but usually the pi is plugged into a dedicated 2+ amp adapter.

Just now I had it instead running off a 3.8 A powered hub, which I *think* is unregulated.  Anyway, I plugged in the HD and suddenly the red PWR led started blinking steadily, about 1 Hz.

The pi itself remained operating and responsive and the blinking stopped when I unplugged the HD.  I shut the pi down, plugged it in with a dedicated adapter, and put the HD back in, everything is fine.

Is this a documented/recognized feature of the (some of the) newer (+ and beyond) models?

Comment: I have seen the same behavior with model 2's

Comment: I experienced something similar with my Pi3. I expected to have no problems with a 2A supply, but tracked it down to the cable. There doesn't seem to be any supply of good microUSB cables so I made my own. Incidentally the APX803 is 4.63±0.07V so even if the LED is on the supply can be below minimum 4.75V.

Comment: Actually the "dedicated adapter" is a 2.1 A USB charger using the exact same cable, so in this case I can't blame that; obviously the hub won't put out the ~1 A I'd guess it takes to run the pi with a drive attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the power supply is failing to regulate and dropping out momentarily. The answer below seems to describe a similar scenario and the rpi wiki also mentions that the blinking PWR LED indicates an issue with the power supply.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227280/raspberry-pi-red-light):

> I have a Raspberry Pi B+ connected to an external USB disk, a Seagate
> Portable 1 Tb (no external power source)

> ...

> The red light blinking but everything working fine

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28825003/6004486) by user @tslmy who quotes the [wiki at http://elinux.org](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_blinking):

> Red power LED is blinking

> A blinking red power LED indicates problems
> with the power supply. On model A and B, it is hard-wired to the 3.3V
> power supply rail. If it is blinking, as one user has reported1 it
> means the 5V power supply is dropping out. Use a different power
> supply.
>
> On model B+ (and presumably also the A+), the circuit has been
> improved to give a much more reliable warning of poor power quality.
> **The red power LED is wired to an APX803 supervisor[2] which kicks in
> when the 5V power supply drops below 4.63V[3]. If it does, the LED
> will blink.** Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

From the [APX803 supervisor data-sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/APX803_D-86185.pdf):

> Microprocessors (μPs) and microcontrollers (μC) have a reset input to
> ensure that it starts up in a known state. The APX803/D drive the μP’s
> reset input to prevent code-execution errors during power-up,
> power-down, or brownout conditions. They assert a reset signal
> whenever the VCC supply voltage declines below a preset threshold and
> keep it asserted for a fixed period of time after VCC has risen above
> the reset threshold

If the [data-sheet for the model B+](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi/raspberry-pi-b-plus-reduced-schematics.pdf) is correct, the APX803 is hooked up to the red PWR LED as the wiki states. I can't account for the blinking (could it be caused by C6? Is it actually the raw input power drops you're seeing? Is it a feature of the APX803?) but it certainly shows that the APX803 can make or break the ground connection of D1 (red LED) via Q1 (depletion-mode n-channel MOSFET):

[image: Raspberry Pi Model B+ APX803 brown-out detection circuit]