# How does RPi "know" when it hasn't got enough power

Tags: power, sensor

When running X and when it's not content that it can draw enough power from the adapter, my RPi displays an RGB colour square on the screen. (At least, I THINK that's what the RGB colour square indicates.)

How does it sense that there's not enough juice available?

It doesn't die or reboot: it seems to be able to sense when there's not enough current available. Is it sensing a voltage drop in the supply, for example?

Comment: If you search you will find a more detailed answer.  If the voltage drops below 4.65V the warning is shown.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45602/blinking-pwr-when-not-enough-current-available/45613#45613). It's not shown in the circuit diagram in my answer to that question, but I think the output of the APX803 comparator IC is connected to a GPIO input on the CPU. It's also hard-wired to the red LED which makes it blink when the voltage drops (and the voltage drops as a result of high current draw).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi (at least all since B+) has a power monitor - the APX803 chip triggers if voltage falls below 4.63±0.07V. This drives the power LED and is connected to a pin on the chip.

In fact the Pi will run at lower voltages as it requires 3.3V and has an on-board regulator. The lower voltage may impact peripherals.

Comment: Many thanks. That's bothersome. I was hoping to tap into it to try to calculate the power being drawn for the max available, but it rather looks like it's a fixed hardware trigger.